# Symfony2 Full Calendar On Adding Multiple Event on Single Slot Take Next Day in Mozilla and Chrome Works Fine

Tags: symfony, fullcalendar

In chrome it works perfectly fine.
In Firefox, when I click in middle of slot, it works fine. But When I click at end of slot, it take next date.

For reference I have recorded video which will give problem insights --
https://youtu.be/QBwyR-xn_tw

```
    $('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev, next, today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
    },
    lazyFetching: true,
    allDayDefault: false,
    disableResizing: true,
    editable: true,
    dragScroll: true,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    slotMinutes: 15,
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    allDaySlot: false,
    minDate: 0,
    minTime: 9,
    maxTime: 23,
    firstHour: currentHour,
    axisFormat: 'htt { - htt}',
    dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

        var mdate = new Date(date);
        alert(mdate);
        exit;
```

Here when I do alert in Google Chrome in any part of slot it works perfectly fine and give me correct date in which I have clicked.

But in firefox, when I click at end of slot it give me next date while I click in middle of slot, it gives  correct date.

Comment: A video is not a good [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try posting your relevant code and maybe we can help.

Comment: I have edited question, with code insights.